Is there a way to render dynamic headings in Quarto using R?
I have several Quarto documents whose headings change dynamically. So far, I have manually entered them, but it needs to be reproducible with different datasets.
Say I have this set of model numbers as a column in a tibble.
Model <- sample(1:1000)
models <- tibble(Model = Model[1:10])

I want to dynamically create a Header 2 sized header using the values in the models$Model column. Here is what I've tried in a code chunk:
{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

header <- paste0('Model #', models$Model[[1]])

cat(paste0('##', header))

Unfortunately, this only outputs a normal text with two ## in front of it, like so:
##Model #687
Is there a way to render this as a header? Thank you!!

You have to add a space to separate the ## from the title, e.g. you can use paste instead of paste0 but actually neither is required, i.e. you can use cat without paste(0):
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
set.seed(123)

Model <- sample(1:1000)
models <- data.frame(Model = Model[1:10])
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
header <- paste0('Model #', models$Model[[1]])

cat(paste('##', header))
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
header <- paste0('Model #', models$Model[[1]])

cat('##', header)
```



Aw man I should've thought about that! Obviously you need the space. Thank you so much for geting back to me so quickly! You're the best @stefan !
